# Displaying a Random Database Item to View -- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, view, controller

I've researching the answer to this question for a while and can't figure it out. I'm trying to build a view that displays a random item from the database (I'm eventually going to make a future implementation to do it via button-click). I have no idea whats wrong.

I have a scaffold called Answers that just displays text. In my Answers Controller, I built a custom method called random:

```
def index
  @answers = Answer.all
end

def show
end

def random
  # @randitem = @items[rand(items.count)] 
  @randanswer = Answer.random_answer
end
```

In my models:

```
  class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.random_answer
    Answer.order("RAND()").first
  end
end
```

Finally, in my views/random.html.erb:

```
<!--Doesn't work-->
<%= link_to @randanswer.answer_response, link_to_answer(@randanswer) %>
```

The a folder screenshot:
[image]

I'm just about at my wits end with this, which is frustrating because I feel like this is a very simple problem. Any suggestions or helpful resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just, find with offset

```
# Rails 4
def self.random_answer
  offset = rand(Answer.count)
  Answer.offset(offset).first
end

# Rails 3
def self.random_answer
  offset = rand(Answer.count)
  Answer.first(:offset => offset)
end
```

I hope it helps

Edited:

Since `Answer.order("RAND()").first` works fine with MySQL, also you can use `Answer.order("RANDOM()").first` with PostgreSQL, or with offset you can do it with confidence it works.

Comment: this did the trick. I modified my views/random.html.erb to: <%= link_to @randanswer.answer_response %>, and it worked perfectly with your #rails 4 version.

Comment: Answer.order("RANDOM()").first

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach, in my opinion, is to use Ruby's sample method:

```
def self.random_answer
  Answer.all.sample
end
```

OR

```
def self.random_answer
  Answer.order(:column_name).sample
end
```

Even better, I would eliminate your model's `random_answer` method and define the `AnswersController` method as:

```
def random
  @randanswer = Answer.all.sample
end
```

Ruby Doc reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-sample