# Rails - Nested Form - Randomise all the individual fields a user posts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

A user can create by post, adding as many nested text fields on the fly as they wish by clicking the 'addtext' button [**new.html.erb**]

If a user, for example, creates a post with three text fields
(**Text1 Text2 Text3**)

[image]

Then another post with three text fields
(**TextA TextB TextC**)

[image]

This will currently display in the browser [**index.html.erb**] as either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErOLP.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/id6tk.jpg due to .order("RANDOM()") [**index action**]

However, I am trying to output a randomised list of all the text fields the user posts. For instance, I want to output & randomise over (**Text1 Text2 Text3 TextA TextB TextC**) in its entirety. In other words, my goal is to output a random assortment of all the text fields individually (**TextA Text2 TextC Text1 Text3 TextB**)

I can't get this to work via my **index action** & **index.html.erb**

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

**new.html.erb**

```
<button id='addtext'>text</button>

<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :things do |ff| %>
 <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @posts = Post.includes(:things).all.order("RANDOM()")
  end 

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<@posts.each do |post| %>
 <% post.things.each do |thing| %>

  <%= thing.try(:text) %>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160227154831) do

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "tag_id"
 t.integer  "taggable_id"
 t.string   "taggable_type"
 t.integer  "tagger_id"
 t.string   "tagger_type"
 t.string   "context",       limit: 128
 t.datetime "created_at"
end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string  "name"
 t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
end

add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "text"
 t.integer  "post_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
 t.integer  "order"
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following
posts_controller.rb

```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @things = Thing.all
    end 

   end
```

in index.html.erb

```
    <% @things.shuffle.each do |thing| %>

     <%= thing.try(:text) %>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi - this didn't work :( - thank you for your feedback though!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want all things for the current user, sorted randomly, this will work:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @things = Thing.joins(post: :user).where(users: { id: current_user.id }).order("RANDOM()")
  end 
end
```

Shuffling in the DB (= ordering randomly) is also preferable to shuffling in ruby, as it is faster.

Edit: more elegantly, you could add a has_many :through relation to be able to access the current_user's things directly by doing current_user.things. However I leave that exercise to you... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @posts = Post.includes(:things).find(:all, :order =>"RANDOM()", :limit => 10)
  end 

end
```

Also MySQL uses RAND() instead of RANDOM().

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help! Unfortunately, that causes this error: "Couldn't find all Posts with 'id': (all, {:order=>"RANDOM()", :limit=>10}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)"

Comment: Hmm. Did you try using RAND() instead of random if you're on SQLite or MySQL. You can also use it by offset. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002114/displaying-a-random-database-item-to-view-rails)

Comment: Using SQLite at the moment - still no luck - thank you for the link!